# How to create PHP code to send SMS with Getasms API?

Tags: php, xml, api, sms

I want to create PHP code to send SMS with API access. I have some documentation but I couldn't understand how to use.

Documentation can view here :

https://dochub.com/gofurtriad/OWbZzP/getasms_api_12082015?dt=6j4ls46xqdwwcmj3

And this some function I have created but always show error 
like this:

> Must provide APIKey parameter for authentication.

This is my function:

```
function create($id, $token, $sms, $to){
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><api></api>');
$xml->addAttribute('version', '1.0');

$xml->addChild('id_client', $id);
$xml->addChild('api_key', $token);

$sends = $xml->addChild('sends');
$send = $sends->addChild('send');

$send->addChild('message', $sms);
$send->addChild('to', $to);

return $xml->asXML();
}
```

Comment: where are you making the api request?

Comment: https://api.getasms.com/api/v1/send/add_single.xml

Comment: All this is doing is building a string of XML - if you're getting an API error back, you must be sending it somehow.

Comment: I meant where in you code you make the call, all I see, is a function that returns an XML, not an API call.

Comment: function create($id, $token,$to,$sms){
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><api></api>');
$xml->addAttribute('version', '1');
$xml->addChild('id_client', $id);
$xml->addChild('api_key', $token);
$xml->addChild('message', $sms);
$xml->addChild('to', $to);
`code`
return $xml->asXML();
}
$body = create($data['user_api'], $data['password'], $this->input->post('to'), $this->input->post('message'));
$headers = array('Content-Type' => 'application/xml');
$request = Requests::post('http://long',$headers, $body);
echo json_encode ($request->body);